# How to change the current line in BASH using regex

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

My task is to change all function names in C source code (definitions, declarations and comments) which have only one underscore and only small letters. For example, my_func(void) ----> myFunc(void). How should I do it? In my code I check if the line of the file contains name of function which I have to change, but I have no idea how to do it. Or may be this task has a more efficient and better solution?

```
while read line; do
   if [[ "$line" =~ ^(int|char|float|long|short|void|double)?[[:space:]]?[^_]([a-z0-9]+[_]?)+[(]([a-z[:space:]])*[)][:space:]*[{]? ]]; then
      # here should be the code
   fi
done < ${FILENAMES[i]}
```

I understand that here should be used 'sed' like

```
sed -i 's/_//' ${FILENAMES[i]}
```

but this command changes all lines of my file, not only what I want and have to change. Thanks.

Comment: You can tell sed to only act on lines that match a regexp.. see https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regexp-Addresses for details. (Especially note the bit about BRE vs ERE and how to enable the latter)

Comment: Try `sed -E -i ':a; s/^((int|char|float|long|short|void|double)?[[:space:]]*[[:alnum:]]*)_([[:alnum:]_]*\([^()]*\))/\1\3/; ta;' file`, see [demo](http://ideone.com/WMC1gN).

Comment: Anything you attempt with a regexp will not be robust but if you add some sample code in the restricted style you have to operate on then we can probably help you wrtie a tool to operate on just that specific subset of C. See also [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: It is not easy what you are asking. It would be better to use a dedicated programmers tool for this. Have a look at NetBeans or so. It will parse your code fully and allow you to change the name of functions in a single step. I would not trust awk or sed with this as anything might happen with it. It is tough to distinguish between variables with underscores and function names containing underscores.